# What factors affect the speed of a VPN connection?

Tags: vpn, performance, hardware, network-speed, software

What hardware/software factors affect the speed of a VPN connection between two computers (1 Gbps network cards) on a lan with just a 1 Gbps switch between them ?

More vague : Is it possible to achieve a VPN speed over 100 Mbps with an average Joe hardware configuration?

Comment: 1. The VPN hardware/ software in use. VPN type and encryption. 
2. Sure you can. I use either SoftEther VPN or tinc for the purpose of VPN. 
Add more details about the project for more specific answers.

Comment: fyi, Some switch can make the traffic encrypted between port without any need of vpn software.

Answer (score 0):

Speed factors will be:

The speed of the NIC and the Switches
The speed of the bandwidth over the WAN or link.

It sounds as if you are doing a VPN over a LAN so with the 1GBPS connection between the two PC’s, 100mbps should be doable. If you are getting slower network speeds than expected check the configuration of the NIC’s, check for errors logging on the NIC’s and switch, ensure everything is full duplex, network teaming working properly, etc. Also check the config of the VPN software you are using, ensure the configs are the same and optimized on both VPN machines.